# How can I get LinkedIn activity and updates to wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I need to bring LinkedIn activity and updates to my WordPress site.

How can I get that?

Is there any plugin available?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more elaborate on your requirements and your programming language. Its very difficult to get a good answer if you are not doing that. Please read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/linkedin-sc/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linkedin.com/opensocialInstallation/preview?_applicationId=2200

Comment: This is to post updates to our linkdin profile . But I need just opposite of that, fetch updates from my linkdin account and display it to My wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that lets you post your LinkedIn updates and also discussions from a LinkedIn group on your WordPress site.

http://codecanyon.net/item/linkedin-social-feed/4449006

Answer (score 0):

This plugin lets you show group information such as discussions and member info on your wordpress site. Visitors to your site can also participate in discussions and join the group: http://www.linkedingroupsforwp.com/

Comment: FYI, you have to pay to use this plugin, it's not free.

Comment: This is for LinkedIn groups, not for your personal LinkedIn profile.